# How to lock on key in a ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I am caching an object, which is created by a thread, into a map. The creation of the object is expensive, so I don't want multiple threads running to create the object because the put() hasn't returned. Once a thread tries to create an object for that key, other threads shouldn't try to create the object, even if put is not yet complete. Will using computeIfAbsent() work to acquire a 'lock' on that particular key? If not, is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: For a proper, efficient and lightweight Java 8 caching library, you could have a look at [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Population). It abstracts away the stuff you're worrying about here. For Java < 8, [Guava caches](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) provide pretty much the same functionality.

Comment: I ended up using a Guava LoadingCache, like you said it does everything I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Will using computeIfAbsent() work to acquire a 'lock' on that particular key?

Yes; per [the Javadoc for `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-):

> The entire method invocation is performed atomically, so the function is applied at most once per key.

That's really the whole point of the method.

However, to be clear, the lock is not completely specific to that one key; rather, `ConcurrentHashMap` typically works by splitting the map into multiple segments, and having one lock per segment. This allows a great deal of concurrency, and is usually the most efficient approach; but you should be aware that it means that some threads might block on your object creation even if they're not actually touching the same key.

If this is a problem for you, then another approach is to use something like `ConcurrentHashMap<K, AtomicReference<V>>` to decouple *adding* the map entry from *populating* the map entry. (`AtomicReference<V>` doesn't have a `computeIfAbsent` method, but at that point you can just use normal double-checked locking with a combination of `get()` and `synchronized`.)

Comment: Or use a caching library?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar requirement, though in my case it was OK if multiple concurrent threads created objects to put in the map, as long as only one thread ended up actually putting its object. For that, I ended up using this method:

> ### [putIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-)
>
> ```
> public V putIfAbsent(K key, V value);
> ```
>
> If the specified key is not already associated with a value, associate it with the given value. This is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> if (!map.containsKey(key))
>    return map.put(key, value);
> else
>    return map.get(key);
> ```
>
> except that the action is performed atomically.